# Gracefuly handle exceptions in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, cluster-computing

I am using nodejs to build an offline cache system for a web service. 
Basically, it polls the web service's public methods once in a while and caches the data in memcached.
Works just fine.

However, I want it to be bullet proof and survive any uncaught exceptions, that bring down the server.
I have read around about different approaches and I believe that the cluster module is really good for my needs. However, I will not be using all the CPU cores for my purpose, as I only 1 thread running and updating the cache.

The only reason I will be using it, is to allow for graceful kill of the worker and easily fork a new one

```
var memwatch = require('memwatch'),
    cluster = require('cluster');

if (cluster.isMaster) {

    console.log('start cluster with 1 workers');
    cluster.fork();
    cluster.on('exit', function(worker) {
        console.log('worker %s died. restart...', worker.process.pid);
        cluster.fork();
    });
} else {
    var http = require('http'),
        app = require("./app.js");
    http.createServer().listen(9000);
    app.init();
}

process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.error((new Date).toUTCString() + ' uncaughtException:', err.message)
    console.error(err.stack)
    process.exit(1)
})

memwatch.on("leak", function(){
    console.log("leak detected");
});
```

Would you consider it a correct approach to my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running just one worker, it's easier to use supervisors like `forever` or `pm2`, they are specifically written for this task. If you plan to add more workers and use cluster load-balancing then yes, it's undoubtedly a correct approach.